# spnego authentication stops working when CAS deployed

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, kerberos, cas, spnego

I have a working tomcat instance where the tomcat-manager applet authenticates with SPNEGO.
When I deploy CAS - configured to use SPNEGO - , the following happens:

- right after the deployment, both the manager applet and CAS works as expected
- after tomcat restart, none of them works, both of them throws exceptions (see below)
- if I undeploy CAS, the manager applet still does not work until tomcat restart

I have assumed that that applications should not modify the behaviour of other applications, and hence using CAS for authentication is voluntary. If this was true, then this behaviour would be an error. If not, then I would assume that CAS should **replace** the authentication of the application, in which case it would still be an error.
However I also assume that I miss some important information about how CAS/tomcat should work.
In short: is it an error to be reported, and/or should I learn more about how CAS/tomcat should work (and where?)

Exception when trying to login to the manager applet:

```
Apr 30 08:57:03 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1 1 2013-04-30T06:57:03.222Z tomcat http-bio-8080-exec-1 21438   192.168.1.10 - - [30/Apr/2013:06:57:03 +0000] "GET /manager/ HTTP/1.1" 302 -
Apr 30 08:57:03 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1 1 2013-04-30T06:57:03.301Z tomcat http-bio-8080-exec-2 21438   192.168.1.10 - - [30/Apr/2013:06:57:03 +0000] "GET /manager/html?org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=146B55AA6642928501CA00F62409FCE8 HTTP/1.1" 401 2486
Apr 30 08:57:03 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1 1 2013-04-30T06:57:03.348Z tomcat http-bio-8080-exec-3 21438   192.168.1.10 - - [30/Apr/2013:06:57:03 +0000] "GET /manager/html?org.apache.catalina.filters.CSRF_NONCE=146B55AA6642928501CA00F62409FCE8 HTTP/1.1" 500 1000
Apr 30 08:57:04 s_catalina@tomcat Apr 30, 2013 6:57:03 AM org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SpnegoAuthenticator authenticate
Apr 30 08:57:04 s_catalina@tomcat SEVERE: Unable to login as the service principal
Apr 30 08:57:04 s_catalina@tomcat javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: No LoginModules configured for com.sun.security.jgss.krb5.accept
Apr 30 08:57:04 s_catalina@tomcat   at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.init(LoginContext.java:273)
Apr 30 08:57:04 s_catalina@tomcat   at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.<init>(LoginContext.java:349)
Apr 30 08:57:04 s_catalina@tomcat   at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SpnegoAuthenticator.authenticate(SpnegoAuthenticator.java:195)
Apr 30 08:57:04 s_catalina@tomcat   at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:544)
Apr 30 08:57:04 s_catalina@tomcat   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
Apr 30 08:57:04 s_catalina@tomcat   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
Apr 30 08:57:04 s_catalina@tomcat   at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
Apr 30 08:57:04 s_catalina@tomcat   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
Apr 30 08:57:04 s_catalina@tomcat   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
Apr 30 08:57:04 s_catalina@tomcat   at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
Apr 30 08:57:04 s_catalina@tomcat   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
Apr 30 08:57:04 s_catalina@tomcat   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
Apr 30 08:57:04 s_catalina@tomcat   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
Apr 30 08:57:04 s_catalina@tomcat   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
Apr 30 08:57:04 s_catalina@tomcat   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

same with CAS:

```
Apr 30 08:59:58 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1 1 2013-04-30T06:59:58.104Z tomcat http-bio-8080-exec-4 21438   192.168.1.10 - - [30/Apr/2013:06:59:58 +0000] "GET /cas/ HTTP/1.1" 302 -
Apr 30 08:59:58 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1 1 2013-04-30T06:59:58.937Z tomcat http-bio-8080-exec-5 21438   192.168.1.10 - - [30/Apr/2013:06:59:58 +0000] "GET /cas/login HTTP/1.1" 401 954
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat 2013-04-30 06:59:58,761 INFO [org.jasig.cas.web.flow.InitialFlowSetupAction] - <Setting path for cookies to: /cas/>
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat jcifs.spnego.AuthenticationException: Error performing Kerberos authentication: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat   at jcifs.spnego.Authentication.processKerberos(Authentication.java:447)
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat   at jcifs.spnego.Authentication.processSpnego(Authentication.java:346)
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat   at jcifs.spnego.Authentication.process(Authentication.java:235)
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat   at org.jasig.cas.support.spnego.authentication.handler.support.JCIFSSpnegoAuthenticationHandler.doAuthentication(JCIFSSpnegoAuthenticationHandler.java:70)
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat   at org.jasig.cas.authentication.handler.support.AbstractPreAndPostProcessingAuthenticationHandler.authenticate_aroundBody2(AbstractPreAndPostProcessingAuthenticationHandler.java:85)
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat   at org.jasig.cas.authentication.handler.support.AbstractPreAndPostProcessingAuthenticationHandler.authenticate_aroundBody3$advice(AbstractPreAndPostProcessingAuthenticationHandler.java:57)
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat   at org.jasig.cas.authentication.handler.support.AbstractPreAndPostProcessingAuthenticationHandler.authenticate(AbstractPreAndPostProcessingAuthenticationHandler.java:1)
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat   at org.jasig.cas.authentication.AuthenticationManagerImpl.authenticateAndObtainPrincipal(AuthenticationManagerImpl.java:93)
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat   at org.jasig.cas.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationManager.authenticate_aroundBody0(AbstractAuthenticationManager.java:57)
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat   at org.jasig.cas.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationManager.authenticate_aroundBody1$advice(AbstractAuthenticationManager.java:57)
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat   at org.jasig.cas.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationManager.authenticate(AbstractAuthenticationManager.java:1)
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

[... 149 more]

Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat   at jcifs.spnego.Authentication$ServerAction.run(Authentication.java:511)
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat   at jcifs.spnego.Authentication.processKerberos(Authentication.java:430)
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat   ... 160 more
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat Caused by: GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Attempt to obtain new ACCEPT credentials failed!)
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat   at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5AcceptCredential.getInstance(Krb5AcceptCredential.java:81)
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat   at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5MechFactory.getCredentialElement(Krb5MechFactory.java:126)
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat   at sun.security.jgss.GSSManagerImpl.getCredentialElement(GSSManagerImpl.java:192)
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat   at sun.security.jgss.GSSCredentialImpl.add(GSSCredentialImpl.java:406)
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat   at sun.security.jgss.GSSCredentialImpl.<init>(GSSCredentialImpl.java:60)
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat   at sun.security.jgss.GSSManagerImpl.createCredential(GSSManagerImpl.java:153)
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat   ... 166 more
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Unable to obtain Princpal Name for authentication 
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat   at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.promptForName(Krb5LoginModule.java:796)
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat   at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.attemptAuthentication(Krb5LoginModule.java:667)
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat   at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.login(Krb5LoginModule.java:580)
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat   at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:784)
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat   at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:203)
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat   at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$5.run(LoginContext.java:721)
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat   at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$5.run(LoginContext.java:719)
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat   at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokeCreatorPriv(LoginContext.java:718)
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat   at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:590)
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat   at sun.security.jgss.GSSUtil.login(GSSUtil.java:255)
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat   at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5Util.getServiceCreds(Krb5Util.java:334)
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat   at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5AcceptCredential$1.run(Krb5AcceptCredential.java:76)
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat   at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5AcceptCredential$1.run(Krb5AcceptCredential.java:74)
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat   at sun.security.jgss.krb5.Krb5AcceptCredential.getInstance(Krb5AcceptCredential.java:73)
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat   ... 171 more
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat 2013-04-30 06:59:59,163 INFO [org.jasig.cas.authentication.AuthenticationManagerImpl] - <org.jasig.cas.support.spnego.authentication.handler.support.JCIFSSpnegoAuthenticationHandler failed authenticating unknown>
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat 2013-04-30 06:59:59,171 INFO [com.github.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] - <Audit trail record BEGIN
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat =============================================================
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat WHO: unknown
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat WHAT: supplied credentials: unknown
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat ACTION: AUTHENTICATION_FAILED
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat APPLICATION: CAS
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat WHEN: Tue Apr 30 06:59:59 GMT 2013
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 192.168.1.10
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat SERVER IP ADDRESS: 192.168.1.29
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat =============================================================
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat >
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat 2013-04-30 06:59:59,174 INFO [com.github.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] - <Audit trail record BEGIN
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat =============================================================
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat WHO: unknown
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat WHAT: :jcifs.spnego.AuthenticationException: Error performing Kerberos authentication: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat ACTION: TICKET_GRANTING_TICKET_NOT_CREATED
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat APPLICATION: CAS
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat WHEN: Tue Apr 30 06:59:59 GMT 2013
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 192.168.1.10
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat SERVER IP ADDRESS: 192.168.1.29
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat =============================================================
Apr 30 08:59:59 s_catalina@tomcat >
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your jaas.conf is incorrectly written. The exception

```
javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: No LoginModules configured for com.sun.security.jgss.krb5.accept
```

basically means that you have a missing entry in your jaas.conf. Inside the tomcat/conf folder you have to write/modify the jaas.conf

A sample module is as follows(append this to existing jaas.conf):-

```
com.sun.security.jgss.krb5.accept {
com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
doNotPrompt=true
principal="YOUR PRINCIPAL ASSOCIATED WITH KEYTAB"
useKeyTab=true
keyTab="CORRECT KEYTAB FILE"
storeKey=true
debug=true;
};
```

This is ofcourse assuming you have a keytab for the server side. This also assumes you havent manually specified in the cas deployment a custom jaas.conf(could have some other names also). In case of a custom deployment, append this entry to the custom jaas.conf

I am assuming(here i might be wrong) that cas is the client. In that case you need to specify a com.sun.security.jgss.krb5.initiate module in its default jaas.conf(i dont know where its location is or should be). In that you can use SSO(single sign authentication) by using:-

```
useTicketCache=true
```

and stating useKeyTab=false, which should pickup your default credential and generate a principal name.

If you still have problems,give the output of all your *.conf files in both tomcat and cas installations

Comment: I believe my jaas.conf is correct. SPNEGO does work if CAS is not deployed.
The output of 'git diff 0a9330fd0758e6a19a6491b1e191651623408a89 -- tomcat7 default/tomcat7' is at http://paste.ubuntu.com/5626376/
The output of git diff 3d44888d193d541d97d8410db1c5320fd8d734ab -- share/tomcat7* is at http://paste.ubuntu.com/5626378/

Comment: what is bugging me is the fact that you have specified appname in the jaas realm as "PortalRealm", whereas you have no such entry in any jaas.conf. I dont know if this will solve your problem but you can try two things. First define an entry in the tomcat jaas.conf with Portal Realm and isInitiatore=false. Secondly set option -Djava.security.auth.login.config="your path", to be absolutely sure cas is not setting some other jaas file during its startup

Comment: I think I found what the problem is. I was experimenting on my tomcat and trying to reproduce the issue. JAAS realm is invoked only when a client is trying to access it(in your case it is cas). Write an entry in your tomcat jaas.conf in the following format:- PortalRealm{ com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required ... }; and fill it with the same options as you have specified in your accept entry